# jfreecharts 2004 (0.9.20) edition vs 2011 edition (1.0.14)

Tags: jfreechart

What facilities or performance capabilities jFreeCharts latest version (1.0.14) provides over 2004 edition (0.9.20).
We have web application having jFreeCharts integrated with 2004 edition .
What advantages we would be having if we upgrade it to the latest version? Classes must be added or modified in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Such information is recorded in the [project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/):

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/
```

You can browse the subversion [repository](https://jfreechart.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jfreechart/):

```
https://jfreechart.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jfreechart/
```

You can examine the project's [revision history](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/2522/log/?path=/trunk):

```
svn log https://jfreechart.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jfreechart/
```

You can check out a local, read-only copy of the [subversion repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/):

```
svn co svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/jfreechart/code/trunk jfreechart-code
```