# Let users edit series in JFreeChart XY plots

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm using JFreeChart to make some graphs in a Java application. I'm trying to figure out how to let the user edit the series paint/stroke. In the Chart Properties window there's a spot for this, but it just says "No editor implemented". Is there a way through the API to provide JFreeChart with an editor for these properties, or do I have to implement one totally separately from the Chart Properties editing window?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for this is described as "incomplete" in [`org.jfree.chart.editor`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/editor/package-summary.html). As a start, you can look in `DefaultChartEditor` to see how the `"BackgroundPaint"` command is handled. You may be able to use `ChartEditorManager` to specify a `ChartEditorFactory` that uses  your custom `ChartEditor`; you may also want to check out a copy of the development branch, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17180748/230513), using `svn`.

Comment: Ah well. Thanks for the pointers, I will look into a custom solution.